# How to get a value returned by user defined function in expl3?

Tags: expl3, programming, latex3

I continue to study `expl3` and I do not understand some behavior of user defined function, which returns an integer value (as I thought).

I want to use the integer number returned by `\count_number_of_elements:n` for further manipulation.

My function `\count_number_of_elements:n` work well and output correct number if I use it directly. But I need to assign its output to an integer variable. How can I did it?

---

MWE

---

A more or less real example: "Longest Collatz sequence" from [Project Euler problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14) (but I want to avoid spoilers here)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_initial_number_int

\cs_new:Nn \count_number_of_elements:n
{
    \int_new:N \l_number_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_number_int {1}
    \int_set:Nn \l_initial_number_int {#1}
    \int_do_while:nn
    {\l_initial_number_int != 1}
    {
    \int_incr:N \l_number_int
    \int_if_even:nTF {\l_initial_number_int}
        {\int_set:Nn \l_initial_number_int {\l_initial_number_int/2} } 
        {\int_set:Nn \l_initial_number_int {3*\l_initial_number_int + 1} }
    }
    \int_use:N \l_number_int
} 

\NewDocumentCommand{\MaxNumber}{m}
{
% Code for defining starting number, produces the longest chain. According to my idea, this code should use integer number produced by \count_number_of_elements:n

% say I need get output of \count_number_of_elements:n
\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\count_number_of_elements:n {#1}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You need it to be expandable. In any case, `\int_eval:n` is already added to the second argument so `\int_add:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 2 + 3 }` works (you don't need to use `\int_eval:n`).

Comment: @Manuel I suspected this. How can I do expandable?

Comment: Well, it depends of what exactly do you want to do with your function, in your example you could just put `#1` as the contents of `\my_function:n` and it would be expandable :) Add a real example case. But it might not be possible to give a general answer unless you clarify what you want to do.

Comment: `\int_set:Nn`  in your `\my_function:n` prevents expansion. An assignment is not expandable, so `\int_add:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\my_function:n{#1}}` in `\Number` will fail

Comment: @Manuel I expect `\Number{34}` in MWE just output the number `34` without any errors.

Comment: @sergiokapone: You must split between storing and typesetting, most likely. I don't see the real application here -- what's the purpose of `\Number{34}` if you could just type `34` then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have no goal for real application now , I'm just experimenting and compare with how it is done in common programming languages. I solved a problem 89 from https://projecteuler.net/ and try to solve some another.

Comment: @sergiokapone In tht edited example you have two options: make it expandable; or just remove the `\int_use:N \l_number_int` from `\count_number_of_elements:n` and edit `\MaxNumber` to be `\count_number_of_elements:n {#1} \int_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_int \l_number_int` and you are done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible approaches here. If you want to allow a function to be used 'inside' something like the second argument of `\int_set:Nn` then it has to be *expandable*. That means it has to use only other functions which are themselves expandable, which in `expl3` means that they are marked in `interface3` with a star. So

```
\cs_new:Npn \my_function:n #1
  {
    \int_eval:n {#1}
  }
```

will work but

```
\cs_new:Npn \my_function:n #1  % See below: should be protected
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \int_eval:n {#1}
  }
```

will not as `\int_set:Nn` is *not* marked with a star.

The second approach is needed where you want to use non-expandable functions: you have to arrange to set a variable for return:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_function:Nn #1#2
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {#2}
    \int_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_int
  }
```

(In a real application there would be more going on, of course.)

---

Note that *many* problems can be tackled by expansion, though this can get very wearing, depending on the issue at hand. Anything involving typesetting or assignment is *specifically excluded*: typesetting doesn't have a  'result' by expansion whilst assignments in TeX are not expandable. (If you use LuaTeX you can do assignments in Lua, but then the entire problem is then different.)

---

Note that you should *not* be using `xparse` here: these are *code level* not *document level* commands. For that reason, I have used `\cs_new:Npn` to create expandable code interfaces and  `\cs_new_protected:Npn` for non-expandable ones.

Comment: I specified my question. I hope it became more clear.

Comment: @sergiokapone I'm not sure what I can add for the general case, though if you like I can suggest how I'd tackle the specific problem

Comment: Thank you. I will try it myself. But if I do not succeed in a few days, I will ask for help.