# Problem with definition variable and the loops in exp3

Tags: expl3, programming, latex3

Continue solveng the problem from my [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372455/how-to-get-a-value-returned-by-user-defined-function-in-expl3/372457#372457)

I have problem with loop `\int_do_while:nn`

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \l_number_int already defined.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

in the code below. When I change the `\l_element_int` by hand, the problem with defining `\l_number_int` does not appear.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_initial_number_int



\cs_new_protected:Npn \count_number_of_elements:Nn #1#2
{
    \int_new:N \l_number_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_number_int {1}
    \int_set:Nn \l_initial_number_int {#2}
    \int_do_while:nn
    {\l_initial_number_int != 1}
    {
    \int_incr:N \l_number_int
    \int_if_even:nTF {\l_initial_number_int}
        {\int_set:Nn \l_initial_number_int {\l_initial_number_int/2} } 
        {\int_set:Nn \l_initial_number_int {3*\l_initial_number_int + 1} }
    }
    \int_set_eq:NN #1 \l_number_int 
} 


\NewDocumentCommand{\MaxNumber}{ m }
{
    \int_new:N \l_bound_element_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_bound_element_int {#1}

    \int_new:N \l_element_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_element_int {2}

    \int_do_while:nn {\l_element_int < \l_bound_element_int}
    {
        \count_number_of_elements:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\int_use:N \l_element_int}
        \int_incr:N \l_element_int
        \int_use:N \l_element_int -- \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int\\

    }

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\MaxNumber{13}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not using the temporary scratch registers `\l_tmpa_int` and `\l_tmpb_int`, for example, instead of using new ones?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok, I will do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never declare variables inside a function.  Declarations (`\..._new:N`) are always global and obviously every name can only be declared once.  This way you can never call a function twice.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_initial_number_int
\int_new:N \l_number_int
\int_new:N \l_bound_element_int
\int_new:N \l_element_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \count_number_of_elements:Nn #1#2
{
    \int_set:Nn \l_number_int {1}
    \int_set:Nn \l_initial_number_int {#2}
    \int_do_while:nn
    {\l_initial_number_int != 1}
    {
    \int_incr:N \l_number_int
    \int_if_even:nTF {\l_initial_number_int}
        {\int_set:Nn \l_initial_number_int {\l_initial_number_int/2} } 
        {\int_set:Nn \l_initial_number_int {3*\l_initial_number_int + 1} }
    }
    \int_set_eq:NN #1 \l_number_int 
} 

\NewDocumentCommand{\MaxNumber}{ m }
{
    \int_set:Nn \l_bound_element_int {#1}

    \int_set:Nn \l_element_int {2}

    \int_do_while:nn {\l_element_int < \l_bound_element_int}
    {
        \count_number_of_elements:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\int_use:N \l_element_int}
        \int_incr:N \l_element_int
        \int_use:N \l_element_int -- \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int\\

    }

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\MaxNumber{13}

\end{document}
```